# I need to recover my source code from the executable

Tags: c, disassembly

It's the middle of the night, and I've accidently overwritten all my work by typing

```
gcc source.c -o source.c
```

I still have the original binary and my only hope is to dissemble it, but I don't know how or what the best tool to use to get the most readable result. I know this probably isn't the right place to post but I'm stressing out. Can someone help me out please?

Comment: Have you looked if there is a .bak? Some editors save a backup copy of the files.

Comment: No disassembler or decompiler will give you the code you wrote. They can give you some code, but it will never be the same (especially if you used optimization).

Comment: *This* is why even you home projects should be under source control. (Actually this is only one of several compelling reasons, but it should be enough.)

Comment: What editor were you using ? Check to see if you have source.c~ or similar. For future reference you need to back up regularly and also learn to use a source control system such as git.

Comment: Thank you everyone for replying. I've checked for hidden files to no avail. I guess I've learnt a very important lesson.

Comment: @Andrew Can you upload the file somewhere, if it's not confidential? I'd like to see how much can be recovered in practice. The default GCC options don't use optimization and don't strip symbols so there should be quite a lot of info left.

Comment: @Igor http://dl.dropbox.com/u/22115721/Broker

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks for uploading the file. As I suspected, it was unstripped so the function names remained. Besides standard boilerplate code I could identify functions `main`, `register_broker`, `connect_exchange` (unused and empty) and `handle_requests`.

I spent a bit of time in IDA Pro and it wasn't too hard to recover the `main()` function. First, here's the original, unmodified listing of `main()` from IDA: http://pastebin.com/sBxhRJMM

To proceed, you need to familiarize yourself with [AMD64 calling convention](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#System_V_AMD64_ABI_convention). To summarize, the first four arguments are passed in RDI(EDI), RSI(ESI), RDX(EDX) and RCX(ECX). The rest is passed on the stack, but all calls in `main()` use only up to four arguments so we don't need to worry about that.

IDA has helpfully labeled arguments of the standard C functions and even renamed some local variables. However, it can be improved and commented further. For example, since we're in `main()`, we know that `argc` (first argument) comes from EDI (since it's an `int` meaning 32-bit, it uses only the low half of RDI) and `argv` comes from RSI (it's a pointer so it uses the full 8 bytes of the register). So, we can rename the local variables into which EDI and RSI are copied:

```
mov     [rbp+argc], edi
mov     [rbp+argv], rsi
```

Next is a simple conditional block:

```
cmp     [rbp+argc], 2
jz      short loc_400EB3            
mov     rax, cs:stderr@@GLIBC_2_2_5 
mov     rdx, rax                    
mov     eax, offset aUsage ; "Usage"
mov     rcx, rdx        ; s         
mov     edx, 5          ; n         
mov     esi, 1          ; size      
mov     rdi, rax        ; ptr       
call    _fwrite                     
mov     edi, 1          ; status    
call    _exit
```

Here we compare argc with 2, and if it is equal, we jump further in the code. If it is *not* equal, we call `fwrite()`. The first argument to it is in `rdi`, and `rdi` is loaded from `rax`, which holds the address of a constant string "Usage". The second argument is in `esi` and is 1, the third in `edx` and is 5, the fourth in `rcx`, which is loaded from `rdx` which has the value of `stderr@@GLIBC_2_2_5`, which is basically a fancy reference to the `stderr` variable from libc. Stringing it all up together, we get:

```
fwrite("Usage", 1, 5, stderr);
```

From my experience, I can say that most likely it is an inlined `fprintf`, since 5 is exactly the length of the string. I.e. the original code probably was:

```
fprintf(stderr, "Usage");
```

Next call is a simple `exit(1);`. Combining both with the comparison, we get:

```
if ( argc != 2 )
{
  fprintf(stderr, "Usage");
  exit(1);
}
```

Continuing in this vein, we can identify other calls and variables they use. It's somewhat tedious to describe it all, so I uploaded a commented version of the disassembly, where I tried to show the equivalent C code for each call. You can see it here: http://pastebin.com/p5sRSwgQ

From that commented version it's not very hard to imagine a possible version of `main()`:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  if ( argc != 2 )
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "Usage");
    exit(1);
  }
  char name[256];
  gethostname(name, sizeof(name));
  struct hostent* _hostent = gethostbyname(name);
  struct in_addr *_addr0 = (struct in_addr *)(_hostent->h_addr_list[0]);
  struct sockaddr_in addr;
  addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  addr.sin_port = htons(0);
  addr.sin_addr.s_addr = _addr0->s_addr;
  char *tmp = (char *)malloc(6);
  sprintf(tmp, "%d", addr.sin_port);
  char *ip_str = inet_ntoa(*_addr0);
  char *newbuf = (char *)malloc(strlen(argv[1]) + strlen(ip_str) + strlen(tmp) + 5);
  strcpy(newbuf, "r");
  strcat(newbuf, " ");
  strcat(newbuf, argv[1]);
  strcat(newbuf, " ");
  strcat(newbuf, ip_str);
  strcat(newbuf, " ");
  strcat(newbuf, tmp);
  register_broker(newbuf);
  int fd = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
  if ( fd < 0 )
  {
    perror("Error creating socket");
    exit(1);
  }
  if ( bind(fd, (struct sockaddr*)&addr, sizeof(addr)) != 0 )
  {
    perror("Error binding socket");
    exit(1);
  }
  if ( listen(fd, 0x80) != 0 )
  {
    perror("Error listening on socket");
    exit(1);
  }
  handle_requests(fd);
}
```

Recovering the other two functions is left an exercise for the reader :)

Answer (score 4):

There are several tools (you can search with Google) but I would suggest to re-code it. The time you will invest into refactoring what a disassebler will return is probably higher than re-coding.

I know it seems obvious but the correct answer would be: restore from a backup (that you should have)

Answer (score 3):

There is unfortunately really no good way to go from the binary back to the source. You can try [Boomerang](http://boomerang.sourceforge.net/), but I really don't expect good results.

Comment: If nothing else, looking through the Boomerang site would give him a good idea of the limitations of decompilation

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, look for a backup source file.  Most editors create files named `.bak` or `filename.c~` with each file save.  On a Windows machine, a forensic software tool might be able to retrieve the last source file(s).  The tool I wrote, `getfile` used to be offered by NTI, but was acquired by Armor Holdings a few years ago—no idea if it is still available.

If the code is runnable, oftentimes running it under the `strace()` utility (a standard component of Linux distributions) can help with some aspects of decoding the program, especially if it is i/o oriented.  Alas, if the program is mostly internal data manipulation, this is not of much use.  `Strace()` creates a log of the system calls and parameters passed by the program; it is an invaluable tool at times for understanding how a program behaves.  for example, `strace date` produces (in part—I've omitted the runtime library startup):

```
clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, {1315760058, 681379835}) = 0
open("/etc/localtime", O_RDONLY)        = 3
fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2819, ...}) = 0
fstat64(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2819, ...}) = 0
mmap2(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xb78b5000
read(3, "TZif2\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\4\0\0\0\4\0\0\0\0"..., 4096) = 2819
_llseek(3, -24, [2795], SEEK_CUR)       = 0
read(3, "\nPST8PDT,M3.2.0,M11.1.0\n", 4096) = 24
_llseek(3, 2818, [2818], SEEK_SET)      = 0
close(3)                                = 0
munmap(0xb78b5000, 4096)                = 0
fstat64(1, {st_mode=S_IFCHR|0620, st_rdev=makedev(136, 0), ...}) = 0
mmap2(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xb78b5000
write(1, "Sun Sep 11 09:54:18 PDT 2011\n", 29Sun Sep 11 09:54:18 PDT 2011) = 29
close(1)                                = 0
munmap(0xb78b5000, 4096)                = 0
close(2)                                = 0
```

As soon as you have anything worth saving:

- Add some sort of source control (git, svn, cvs, ...) maybe more than one
- Use an automated build tool, like `make` to avoid silly mistakes
- Make backups once in a while.  Even when I am at a stone-knives-and-bear-skins client, I can still email myself source files for a last-ditch backup mechanism.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [dcc](http://itee.uq.edu.au/%7Ecristina/dcc.html). But, next time, you **should** use Git ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can try disassembling with `objdump -d <filename>`.

You can also look at the symbol names with the `nm` utility to jog your memory and help recode the source.

The commercial [IDA Pro](http://www.hex-rays.com/idapro/) disassembler/debugger is popular in software reverse engineering. Unfortunately, reverse engineering a binary is slow and difficult work.

Comment: That's not really going to help much, is it ?

Comment: @Paul R, no, it isn't. The OP is pretty much out of luck.

Comment: Wow, why so much negativity? In my opinion this is a much better way than strace.